# My website doesnt load index.html if i dont write it manually

Tags: html, .htaccess

I recently bought a website to play with, but I immediately had a problem.

My website doesn't load the index.html when I just connect to mydomain.com. If I write it manually (mydomain.com/index.html) everything works perfectly. I tried to change  the .htaccess file to direct all traffic to my index.html page with the following line, but the problem remains:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

Any ideas to solve the problem?

Comment: Do you have another index file, like `index.php`?

Answer (score 0):

Please provide the web host and/or server type (windows, linux, etc) to help further answer your question.

As a start some web servers (windows/iis) expect different file names for the default html file. Godady.com has a list of different file names for Linux and Windows at this url: https://www.godaddy.com/help/what-file-displays-when-someone-browses-to-my-domain-name-60

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This `DirectoryIndex index.html` has to be set in httpd.conf  file. In your httpd.conf, you might have disabled .htaccess with `AllowOverride none`. That is why your .htaccess is not working